Multi-targeting in NuGet package - wrong version referenced
This is my nuget package structure, following the guide here:

When this package is installed in a project targeting .Net8.0, I get the warning that it was restored for .Net Frameworks 4.6.1 to 4.8.2, and that it may not be fully compatible with my project. How to troubleshoot this? I tried this with a new project targeting .Net8.0 and was able to reproduce the issue. Why would nuget not pick up the correct target framework when installing?
This is a legacy assembly that needs to be compatible with .Net8, but some of its code has to remain in v4.5.2. That is the reason for having the "base" assembly for both versions, with an assembly that interfaces with the actual project that references it. I am not sure if this structure is a problem, and if it is then how to solve this.

May I know that whether you are getting compiling error or just a warning? Per my understanding, if it's just a warning, we might not need to troubleshoot it as it might be an expected behavior.

@TinyWang it is just a warning. Could you please explain why it is expected behavior when a .Net8 assembly is available for referencing, but the project wouldn't use it?

Might be related to missing some of the configuration? I referred to this document and it points to a configuration which might requires to set <TargetFrameworks>net452;net80</TargetFrameworks>, have you configured it?

@TinyWang I think that is applicable to an assembly that supports 2 target frameworks. In my case, there are 2 separate assemblies to support each framework and I expect nuget to serve up the appropriate one when my package is installed

Hi, per my understanding, I think when installed a nuget package to use it somewhere, the app should use the corresponding version package. If we already followed the official document to set 2 target frameworks in the same app it should work. Could you please provide a minimal sample for further investigation if your app doesn't work well?
